# Highcharts doesnt work on pagination next page

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pagination

I am using jquery pagination. I am displaying 5 records per page. That means I am showing 5 highcharts. Now the problem is when I click on Next button. Next page data gets displayed but chart is not showing. Again when I click on prev button chart is not showing.

I am appending data in div without page refresh.

Chart type is Column.

Here is the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/shgc60fq/

In data loop I tried this but still its not working

```
    historygraphs(data.id);
    var chart = $('#contacts-history-chart-'+data.id).highcharts();

    var data2 = [5,7];
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["Nov", "Dec"], true);
    chart.series[0].setData(data2,true);
```

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong without any code. The best would be to create jsFiddle demo with recreated issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shgc60fq/2/

Comment: Ok, code in the jsFiddle doesn't work. What kind of errors do you have in Javascript console?

Comment: The issue is highcharts in pagination doesnt work when I click on Next button or prev button it works only on page load what can be the issue

Comment: But what errors do you have in JS console? `ctrl`+`shift`+`j` to open console in Chrome.

Comment: No as such errors when i do cntrl + shift + j

Comment: but what can be the issue it loads first time but doesnt work on Next Prev button click

Comment: this is json data for pagination

Comment: [{"id":"39","firstname":"kagesh"},{"id":"51","firstname":"Oditi"},{"id":"50","firstname":"Sagar"},{"id":"53","firstname":"Salman"},{"id":"52","firstname":"Ojas"}]

Comment: A bit hard to believe that nothing shows up without errors. Do you have this webpage live? So I can **see** that issue? Without live demo we can only guess what may be wrong..

Comment: ok I will setup code for you I will get back to you.

Comment: You are trying to create charts **before** your created HTML containers for them. In short, move `hs(data.id);` **after** `$(".contacts-data").append(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Your Highchart data should be rerendered. 
Let's say you save your highchart data in `var chart`, you can update the data in your complete function like:

```
chart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 3] );
```

assuming your append function has an oncomplete callback.

Comment: Hi, could you please see the code and let me know why highcharts are not working on click of next prev button.

Comment: The code is too much of a mess to have a quick solution, but first of all you should remove all unnecessary code from the success callback and only leave code there which does something with the data. Right now you create a function inside the success callback, while you can simply call that function with `graphAjax(data)` and define the function somewhere else. Same for all the highcharts, the only thing you're changing is the data, you can create the highchart outside the ajax function and update the data per highchart within the success callback.

Comment: Yes I created function for graph after that in data loop I inserted these lines but doesnt work  historygraphs(data.id);
  var chart = $('#contacts-history-chart-'+data.id).highcharts();

  var data2 = [5,7];
  chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(["Nov", "Dec"], true);
  chart.series[0].setData(data2,true);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xAxis' of undefined

Comment: Try this: `chartOptions = {
    series: [{
        data: [1,2,3]
    }]
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions)`

If you log your chart var, does it give output? If undefined, log data.id and see if that has a value

Comment: No still its not working. Should I add code in fiddel ? so that you will look at it

Comment: Sure, but only the needed code for the example, all other you can leave out.